# How to add a row to only one column of a QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with two columns:
"Absolute Links" and "Non Absolute Links".

I want to add each link of a list of links depending on if they are absolute or not. **I only want to insert a row to the corresponding column**.

Is there a method similar to .insertRow() that enables me to do this ?

This what I have tried but it keeps adding me the row to all the columns.

```py
for link in self.links_:
    numRows = self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.rowCount()
    self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.insertRow(numRows)
        if self.isAbsolute(link):
            self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.setItem(numRows, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(link))
        else:
            self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.setItem(numRows, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(link))
```

I have also tried this, using two lists, it doesn't work perfectly and it doesn't add all the links in the lists:

```py
for AbsoluteLink in self.AbsoluteLinks:
        numRows = self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.rowCount()
        self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.insertRow(numRows)
        self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.setItem(numRows, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(AbsoluteLink))


for count, NonAbsoluteLink in enumerate(self.NonAbsoluteLinks):
    self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.setItem(count, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(NonAbsoluteLink))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the second strategy, you could do something like

```
self.AbsoluteLinks.setRowCount(max(len(self.AbsoluteLinks), len(self.NonAbsoluteLinks)))

for row, link in enumerate(self.AbsoluteLinks):
    self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(link))

for row, link in enumerate(self.NonAbsoluteLinks):
    self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(link))
```

(Or you could combine the two for-loops:)

```
self.AbsoluteLinks.setRowCount(max(len(self.AbsoluteLinks), len(self.NonAbsoluteLinks)))
for col, links in enumerate((self.AbsoluteLinks, self.NonAbsoluteLinks)):
    for row, link in enumerate(links):
        self.HTMLLinksTableWidget.setItem(row, col, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(link))
```